# Polite euphemism for death

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I starting a project on domain X. Though it existed before and was already quite famous, an important name N got so popular that it became a bannerman of the whole domain, and the general audience would take N as a representative of the domain.

The problem is that N passed away long ago and the project is to show that a lot has been done in X since then. I'd like my project to have a title that carries this idea. I found that "N is dead" (in reference to Nas' "hip hop is dead", though the main idea is different) too direct and provocative. I don't want to be dismissive on N's contribution, but the project is to highlight all the other talented persons that enriched X.

What I come up so far is "N is no more" but I am not sure it works. I cannot find it in this [Wikipedia page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_expressions_related_to_death) on death-related expression.

As an example, if the project was on English theater, I would call it "Shakespeare is no more"

**Is it a correct (grammatically, provocative but polite enough) way to express this idea?**

Comment: I should note that you used *passed away* in your question, perhaps already providing yourself with an answer.

Comment: [Deceased](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deceased) could work, but it's probably too literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be no more is OK. It does mean dead. But it also means defunct, as when a company goes out of business.

- X is passé [a French term meaning outmoded or outdated]
- X has gone to meet its maker [John Cleese sketch on a parrot; works if you want to be lighthearted]
- X has left the scene
- X is no longer with us [that is a common idiom]

Just some ideas to play with.

Comment: Monty Python's famous [Dead Parrot Sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218), which contains many euphemisms for death, some facetious.  I agree that "N is no longer with us" is probably your best option.  You should probably not use "N has brung down the curtain and joined the choir invisible" unless you want to earn geek cred.  :)

Comment: That is very funny, Andrew (not sure I'm allowed to comment but it really is). I am having a hard time getting my head around the idea of being provocative and dead. But never mind that.